# How to pass map key in JavaScript method call?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a task that requires to display a map key into an alert box.  How can I get the map key in the alert box.

I have tried the below code but I can't change the HTML.

```
<div class="row notranslate">
  <div class="col-md-12 btnspace">
    <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.trackingMap}" var="mcMAP">
      <a 
        href="#" 
        id="amcvalue" 
        class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
        data-akey="${mcMAP.key}" 
        data-amc="${mcMAP.value}"
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#myModal"
        onclick="setAmcValue(${mcMAP.value});">
        <font color="yellow">
          <span id="value">${mcMAP.key}</span>
        </font>
        <%-- --${mcMAP.value} --%>
        <i class="btn-icon-only icon-circle-arrow-right"></i> 
      </a>
      <br />
    </c:forEach>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is JavaScript:

```
function setAmcValue(amc) {
   alert(amc);
   $("#mc1").empty().html(amc);
}
```

I want mcMAP.key as amc value

Comment: You mean you could not update the `onclick="setAmcValue(${mcMAP.value});` into `onclick="setAmcValue(${mcMAP.key});` ?

Comment: i have tried setAmcValue($mcMAP.key}); but its not even calling function like that.- @GabrielCheung

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no there is no error in console.....

Comment: Is your JavaScript file included in the page?

Comment: yes there is file is included....

Answer (score 0):

we just need to change
 `onclick="setAmcValue(${mcMAP.value});"` to `onclick="setAmcValue('${mcMAP.key}');"` and its start working.